Console App - throws NullReferenceException on SqlClientDiagnosticSourceListeners.cs (telemetry.Success = false;) whenever await an async task
I have a console app that start an inhereted class with DI, passing in args and an async function to run:
using M.BusinessLogic.Heartbeat;
using M.BusinessLogic.Heartbeat.Tasks;
using M.Data.DataContexts;
using M.Data.Models;
using M.Heartbeat;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var heart = new Heart(args,
    async (scope) =>
    {
        using var DB = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MDbContext>()!;
        var dbTasks = await (from Tasks in DB.Tasks
                             select Tasks).ToListAsync();

        SelectTask(dbTasks, scope, DB);
    });
await heart.BeatAsync();

the Heart constructor:

heart.BeatSync() looks like this:
public async Task BeatAsync()
{


    var builder = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
    ConfigLoader.LoadConfig(builder.Environment, builder.Services, builder.Configuration, AppInsightsMode.ConsoleApp);

    var config = builder.Configuration.Get<Config>();
    if (config == null)
        throw new Exception("App Config not loaded!");

    builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyAPIGroup, MyAPIGroup>(sp =>
    {
        var h = config.MyAPI;
        return new MyAPI.MyApiGroup(...);
    });
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<HeartBeat.Tasks>();

    builder.Services.AddScoped<HeartBeat.Utilities>();

    //tasks
    builder.Services.AddScoped<HeartBeat.Task1>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<HeartBeat.Task2>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<HeartBeat.Task3>();


    // run the application
    using (IHost host = builder.Build())
    {
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            await RunTasksAsync(scope);
        }
    }

}

SelectTask(...) is the console stuff, which allows the user to select a task and then it will try to run that task (you probably don't need to look at this to see what's going on, it will basically run the task):
async void SelectTask(List<HeartbeatTask> dbTasks, IServiceScope scope, DbContext DB)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nHeartbeat Tasks:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < dbTasks.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {dbTasks[i].Code}");
    }

    Console.Write("\nEnter the number of the task to run. Will run now, even if disabled:\n\n> ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        Console.Write("No input selected.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        bool isParsable = int.TryParse(input, out int result);
        if (!isParsable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a number.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            int selectedTaskNumber = int.Parse(input);


            bool isValid = selectedTaskNumber >= 1 && selectedTaskNumber <= dbTasks.Count;

            if (!isValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid task number selected.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                IHeartbeatTask? Itask;
                Itask = null;

                Itask = Tasks.GetTaskFromCode(dbTasks[selectedTaskNumber - 1].Code!, scope);

                Console.WriteLine($"\nStarted '{Itask.TaskName}' task...");
                await Itask!.RunAsync(heartbeatTaskLog.Id);
                Console.WriteLine($"...finished '{Itask.TaskName}' task.");
    
                // save to db after each task is run
                DB.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    SelectTask(dbTasks, scope, DB);
}

What is a "Task"? Well, it's an aspnet.core, class written in c#, that:

basically looks at the db and then makes changes, and might involve API calls, hence it's asynchronisity

I've noticed that when the Task itself runs, any lines that are await lines to some Async process, I get the following error:

The file is: C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\.vsdbgsrc\[long hex number]\SqlClientDiagnosticSourceListener.cs
Disclaimer: I hope I've given enough info, please ask if you need anything more. This is set up using components that I didn't set up, such as DI, which I am not an expert in. I hope it's not an obvious answer, I'd appreciate any help and hopefully this might help others in future.

This question is similar to: What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Fildor sorry but I obviously don't think this can be fully figured out by being aware of what a NullReferenceException is. This is coming from the point of view of not understanding why this particular case is happening, in the environment it is in. The combined knowledge of all of that is immense, way beyond my level

Well, if you think we could, then you should a) not post code as images, b) post an [mre] and c) give detailed information about what exception happens under what conditions at which exact line of the code.

And just realizing now: you first of all probably want to get rid of async void. Make it async Task instead.

@Fildor it's just 6 lines of code as an image. Sorry. I've done c). Thanks for a suggestion, I'll try it

@Fildor Alas, it did not help. I understand if people don't want to engage without a reproducible sample (I honestly think making one might be too hard, but I might consider it if I get nowhere). I am merely hoping that someone who has had this before, or at least recognises my environment enough to take a good guess (like you did) or point me in the right direction, will be able to comment so I'd appreciate this question not being closed

In the console app, i.e. the first code snippet, I changed

SelectTask(dbTasks, scope, DB);

to

await SelectTask(dbTasks, scope, DB);

